# Getting the contents of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ascx

I'm currently trying to find the element located in an iframe.  The hierarchy goes like this.

html > body > form#form1 > iframe#report-container > html > body > form#form1 > div > pageBreaker

(This is an aspx page, within an aspx page, that uses ascx file within an iframe).

I'm trying to find a good javascript or Jquery method of getting to the pageBreaker element.

I've tried:

```
var jqIframe = $(iframe); 
var doc = jqIframe[0].document.form1; 
var el = doc.getElementById("pageBreaker"); //undefined
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: var jqIframe = $(iframe);
        var doc = jqIframe[0].document.form1;
        var el = doc.getElementById("pageBreaker"); //undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this necessarily.

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrameId').contentDocument;
var desiredElement = iFrame.getElementById('pageBreaker');
```

Using the document API we can easily get the iFrame element and pull the content document out of it. Then it is trivial locating an element via its ID.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  Is there also a way to remove all the class of all of the pageBreaker elements in that iframe?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: Yes, they are just present to a page break, other than that, they aren't significant.

Comment: HTML Ids should be unique, you should use classes where you require a shared identifier.